# Thousand dollars puzzle poor women

Tags: riddle, language

A poor woman and a rich woman are talking about music.

The poor woman says she has studied music and can find a song with any name in it.

The rich woman says "OK, if you can find a song with my son's name in it, I will give you a thousand dollars. His name is Demarcus-Jabari."

The poor woman gives her answer and is instantly $1,000 richer.

What was her answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Happy Birthday to you 'Demarcus-Jabari', Happy Birthday to you.

Comment: correct answer !